# How to retrieve attributes of message written to a SQS queue using Boto?

Tags: amazon-web-services, python

I have the following code snippet.

```
conn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region(region)
q = conn.lookup('myqueue')
m = Message()
m.set_body('My Message')
data = {"UserID": {"data_type": "Number","string_value": "11111"}}
m.message_attributes = user_data
q.write(m)
```

Using this, I have successfully written the attributes I wanted with the message. Now, I wanted to retrieve it. I have tried

```
msg.message_attributes
```

But I have got an empty dictionary only.

Is this the way to retrieve it? Or am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve attributes of message written to a SQS queue using Boto?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056746/how-to-retrieve-attributes-of-message-written-to-a-sqs-queue-using-boto)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got the answer to my question.

For this you must have retrieved the message like this

```
attributes = ['UserID']
msgs = q.get_messages(message_attributes=attributes)
```

Will get msgs as a list. And let msg be msgs[0]
Then the message attribute can be retrieved by the following code.

```
msg.message_attributes['UserID']['string_value']
```